# Setting up octo print and my Raspberry Pi 3 B+ won't show up on on angry IP scanner. How can I find its IP?

Tags: wifi

So I recently ordered a Raspberry Pi 3 B+ off amazon from RS Components and I wan to set up octo print with it, but the IP won't show up on angry IP scanner. I'm not sure what to do since I can't find the octo.local hostname. please let me know any ideas to fix this!

Comment: when I set up octo print on a pi (3A+) it appeared on the network as octopi.local not octo.local - as per step 4 of the installation instructions - perhaps you misunderstood the installation procedure - have you confirmed that the pi is even booting?

Answer (score 1):

Wired or wireless? If you attach a screen to it, it should print the ip address during boot. If not, you can log into it and use `ip address` command to see the address of the network interfaces.